# Using SQL in transaction function in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Can I call SQL/MYSQL queries from my transaction function in Hyperledger Composer?

If so, How can I?

If not, should I go with a Rest Api and Consume it from my transaction function? If there is a better way please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a call-out to the REST endpoint for your SQL query - examples of that are shown here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out. Also observe the comments on achieving deterministic results below.

the example shows you can return results to your Transaction Processor function. As for your query - if you don't already have REST APIs set up for those, there's plenty of [resources](https://jsao.io/2018/04/creating-a-rest-api-handling-get-requests/) out there to help

Comment: For clarity, you need to be very careful about making calls to external services as you need to ensure that the returned results are deterministic in order for endorsement to be satisfied.